# Field out of range error while inserting height into Google Fit API

Tags: java, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

This is my code to insert height using google fit API.
Object height=160.0F;

```
 DataSource dataSource = new DataSource.Builder()
            .setAppPackageName(LoginActivity.this)
            .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_HEIGHT)
            .setType(DataSource.TYPE_RAW)
            .build();

    DataSet heightDataSet = new DataSet(dataSource);
    DataPoint dataPoint = heightDataSet.createDataPoint().setTimeInterval(Helper.getStartTimeOfDay(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis()),
            Helper.getNow(), TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
    if (height instanceof Integer) {
        dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_HEIGHT).getFormat();

        dataPoint = dataPoint.setIntValues((Integer) height);
    } else {
        dataPoint = dataPoint.setFloatValues((Float) height);
    }


    heightDataSet.add(dataPoint);
    Fitness.HistoryApi.insertData(App.gClient, heightDataSet).setResultCallback(new ResolvingResultCallbacks<Status>(LoginActivity.this, 0) {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Status status) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onUnresolvableFailure(Status status) {

        }
    });
```

It gives the error **java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Field out of range**
at line  heightDataSet.add(dataPoint);
Please help.

Comment: The units are probably meters so 160m is a bit tall...

Comment: Thanks a  million! I was trying to insert height in cms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heights are in meters so I think you mean to use 1.6f

Fit as a rule uses SI units so Meters, kg, m/s etc.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error when I used `TimeUnit.HOURS` instead of `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS`.

Comment: i am using milliseconds,, but still get this exception sometime